# Error adding a JWT inbound policy: Error in element 'validate-jwt':Certificate '' could not be resolved

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management, apim

When using Azure APIM to add a inbound policy to verify a JWT, the config editor throws the following error:

`One or more fields contain incorrect values: Error in element 'validate-jwt' on line 16, column 10: Certificate '' could not be resolved.`

I can see it's the `issuer-signing-keys` node causing the problem as removing it allows it to save.
Here is the example of the policies file:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" require-scheme="Bearer">
            <issuer-signing-keys>
                <key>YmVlZg==</key>
            </issuer-signing-keys>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This is a bug we reported on Friday 19th Jun 2020. Recently Microsoft has rolled out a new release that applies to all new instances of APIM. So if you have previously created APIM instance then it would work. We are still awaiting MS to provide hotfix.

Comment: @MukeshKumar Hi, good to know. May i know any feedback link about this bug? Thanks in advance

Comment: @JayGong, This is over my org email so no links, unfortunately. I will post an update here if I will have any reply.

Comment: Here is APIM release note: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/azure-api-management-update-june-2020/

Comment: thanks @MukeshKumar good to know I wasn't doing anything wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Mukesh Kumar

This is a bug we reported on Friday 19th Jun 2020. Recently Microsoft has rolled out a new release that applies to all new instances of APIM. So if you have previously created APIM instance then it would work. We are still awaiting MS to provide hotfix.